# How to return a div with an image element for each document in a firestore collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a bunch of documents containing links to a bunch of different images in a firestore collection. I would like to display an image on my screen for every document in the collection.

Code: (Mildly fragmented because I don't wanna upload my whole project)

```
async function DisplayImageData()
{
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", userUID, "images"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    return(
      <img src={doc.image} />
    );
  });
}
```

It should be stated that I have actually gotten the get/upload part of this process working, so I know that isn't the problem.

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists

Answer (score 1):

```
async function DisplayImageData()
{
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", userUID, "images"));
  return <>(querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
    return(
      <img src={doc.image} />
    );
  }))</>;
}
```

You have to do something like that. Because now the entire list has been returned instead of a single component inside.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue, you need to return something like:

```js
<img src={doc.data().image} />
```

Because the data you want to use is inside the return object of doc.data(). Also you need to use a map instead of a forEach as you can not return something from a forEach function.